# Character SET e Character Encoding - O que são, pra que servem?

Tags: codificação-de-caracteres

O que são, pra que servem?

- Character SET
- Character Encoding

Comment: Eu não vou responder porque este é um dos assuntos que mais causa confusão na computação e acho que uma pessoa muito bem qualificada sobre isto precisaria responder, respostas mais ou menos só vão aumentar a confusão. Eu tenho a impressão que esta é a fonte única de maior número de perguntas aqui. Uma resposta nota 10 viraria canônica pra muita coisa que é perguntada aqui.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basicamente:

**Charset**: Conjunto de caracteres que você pode usar. 
**Encoding**: É a forma como esses caracteres são armazenados na memória.

Sugiro ler a fonte, [este tópico no SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281646/whats-the-difference-between-encoding-and-charset). Ou ainda [esse artigo](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).