# Método "include?" retornando false quando há um caractere na string em Ruby

Tags: string, ruby, include

Sou iniciante em *Ruby* e estou tentando criar um Jogo da Forca para testar meus conhecimentos na linguagem. Em uma parte do código, eu preciso obter uma letra escolhida pelo usuário e verificar se essa letra está presente na palavra a ser encontrada.

Para realizar essa verificação, estou utilizando o método de string `include?`, porém este método está retornando `false` mesmo quando a letra existe na palavra. Para demonstrar isso, eu criei um exemplo de código abaixo:

```
print "Digite uma palavra: "
WORD = gets.downcase           # A palavra que estou digitando é "bola"

print "Digite uma letra: "
char = gets.downcase          

puts WORD.include? char
```

Neste exemplo, se o usuário digitar no segundo `gets` a letra `"a"`, o método retorna `true`, porém se o usuário digitar a letra `"b"`,`"o"` ou `"l"`, o método retorna `false`.

Por que isto ocorre? Como posso resolver o problema?

Comment: Para quem quiser saber, eu estou utilizando a versão `ruby 2.6.5`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isso acontece porque [`gets`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Kernel.html#method-i-gets) retorna não só o texto digitado, mas também o caractere `\n` correspondente ao <kbd>ENTER</kbd> que você digita. Isso pode ser visto se você verificar o tamanho da string e seus codepoints*:

```
print "Digite uma palavra: "
WORD = gets.downcase
p WORD
puts WORD.length
print WORD.codepoints
```

Se você digitar "bola" e der <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, a saída será:

```
"bola\n"
5
[98, 111, 108, 97, 10]
```

Ou seja, o tamanho da string é 5, pois ela corresponde a `bola\n` (as 4 letras da palavra "bola" mais o `\n` que corresponde ao <kbd>ENTER</kbd>).

Pelos codepoints podemos ver que o último caractere é o 10, que de fato [corresponde ao `\n`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a/index.htm).

---

Então quando você digita a letra "a", na verdade `gets` retorna a string `a\n`. E como a string `WORD` contém o valor `bola\n`, de fato a substring `a\n` está inclusa nela.

Mas se você digita a letra "b", ela se torna `b\n`, e esta substring não está inclusa na string `bola\n`. O mesmo acontece com as letras "o" e "l".

Uma forma de resolver é se livrar desse `\n`, usando o [método `chomp`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/String.html#method-i-chomp):

```
print "Digite uma palavra: "
WORD = gets.chomp.downcase

print "Digite uma letra: "
char = gets.chomp.downcase          

puts WORD.include? char
```

---

* Para entender melhor o que é um codepoint, veja [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/394834/112052).

E na verdade `gets` usa o valor da variável `$/` (*input record separator*), que é uma das muitas [variáveis pré-definidas](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/doc/globals_rdoc.html) e cujo valor *default* é `\n`. Mas esta [pode ser alterada](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37348006), se quiser.

Comment: Obrigado, era exatamente o que eu precisa!