# Substituir as letras de uma string por sua respectiva posição do alfabeto

Tags: javascript, string

Preciso substituir cada letra de uma String qualquer por sua respectiva posição no alfabeto. Por exemplo, a string `"faebcd"` deve transformar-se em `"615234"`.

Estou travado na parte de substituir os valores da array `novaFrase` pelos respectivos valores no array `posiçãoLetra`. Segue o código:

```js
const frase = "Birulei Nau"  // Frase de exemplo

const alfabeto = [,"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]; 

const posiçãoLetra = []; // Variável com a posição das letras do alfabeto

// A função abaixo encontra e preenche o array posiçãoLetra com as 
// respectivas posições das letras do alfabeto.

function encontraPosição (alfabeto) {    
    for (let i = 1; i < alfabeto.length; i++) {
        posiçãoLetra.push(alfabeto.indexOf(alfabeto[i],[0]));
    }
}

encontraPosição(alfabeto);


function substituiLetra (frase) {   

    const letrasFrase = frase.split('');
    const novaFrase = letrasFrase.forEach(function (letra){

        // Aqui que eu não to conseguindo destravar. 
        // Não sei se devo usar forEach, filter, map, etc...
        letra.splice(0, posiçãoLetra[0]) 

        console.log(novaFrase);

    });    
}

substituiLetra(frase);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode usar `.map()`, mas é preciso alguns ajustes, como no caso de haver espaços na frase, eliminá-los com replace:

```
frase.replace(/\s/g, '');
```

A expressão `/\s/g` busca todos os espaços.

Outra coisa é converter a frase para minúsculas, porque no caso de uma letra maiúscula, como no seu exemplo "Birulei Nau", não encontraria as letras "B" e "N", já que o JavaScript é *case sentive* (diferencia maiúsculas e minúsculas).

Como na resposta do JeanExtreme002, não precisa criar uma array `alfabeto`, basta uma string com todas as letras, pois cada posição dos caracteres possui um índice, semelhante a uma array, começando do zero (por isso é preciso somar +1).

O código ficaria desta forma:

```js
const frase = "Birulei Nau"  // frase de teste
const alfabeto = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; 

function substituiLetra (frase) {   
   frase = frase.replace(/\s/g, ''); // elimina os espaços
   const novaFrase = frase.split('').map(function (letra){
    
    // este trecho é apenas para mostrar os valores
    console.log(letra +" = "+ Number(alfabeto.indexOf(letra.toLowerCase())+1));
    // remova do código
   
   
      return alfabeto.indexOf(letra.toLowerCase())+1;
   }).join("");  

   return novaFrase; // retorna a string com as posições das letras
}

console.log("Posições: "+ substituiLetra(frase));
```

Answer (score 6):

Você disse que a string `"faebcd"` deve se tornar `"615234"`. Mas e se a string for `"klm"`, então ela se torna `"111213"` (afinal, "k", "l" e "m" são respectivamente a 11ª, 12ª e 13ª letras do alfabeto)? Para manter as coisas simples, vamos assumir que é isso. Também estou assumindo outras premissas:

- vamos considerar somente letras de A a Z (ou seja, espaços, pontuação, dígitos, etc, todos esses serão ignorados). Também vou desconsiderar letras acentuadas.

  - não ficou claro o que você faz com caracteres que não forem letras. No código abaixo, vou assumir que o código correspondente é zero.
- vou fazer o algoritmo *case insensitive*: considera que tanto "A" quanto "a" terão o valor 1, "B" e "b" terão o valor 2, etc ([uma das respostas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/434752/112052) não leva isso em conta, então a letra "B" acaba tendo o valor zero - *não sei se era bem isso que você queria, mas enfim*)

As outras respostas usam um *loop* pelos caracteres da string, e dentro deste *loop* usam `indexOf` ou `map` para verificar a posição da letra no alfabeto. Até aí tudo bem, funciona, mas o que você não percebe é que estes códigos estão criando uma variação do chamado [*Shlemiel the painter's algorithm*](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/).

Basicamente, para cada letra da string, `indexOf` e `map` percorrem a string (ou o array) `alfabeto` para verificar a posição da letra no mesmo. Ou seja, caso a frase seja "Birulei Nau", para a letra "B", verifica-se o alfabeto desde a letra "a" (e se não considerarmos o algoritmo *case insensitive*, ele percorrerá todo o alfabeto, pois não encontrará o "B"). Depois para a letra "i", verifica o alfabeto novamente, começando do "a", depois para a letra "r" mesma coisa, e assim por diante. No final, o `alfabeto` é percorrido várias vezes (claro que na maioria das vezes não será percorrido inteiramente, mas mesmo assim são iterações demais à toa, principalmente se a string tiver vários caracteres que não são letras).

Enfim, uma outra forma de fazer seria:

```js
let frase = "Birulei Nau";
let posicoes = [];
for (let i = 0; i < frase.length; i++) {
    let c = frase.codePointAt(i);
    // se for letra maiúscula, converte para minúscula
    if (65 <= c && c <= 90) c+= 32;
    if (97 <= c && c <= 122) {
        posicoes.push(c - 96);
    } else {
        posicoes.push(0); // não é letra de A a Z, usar zero
    }
}
console.log(posicoes.join(''));
```

Eu uso [`codePointAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/codePointAt) para obter o valor do *code point* de cada caractere (para entender o que é isso, [leia aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/394834/112052)). Para simplificar, as letras de A a Z possuem code points com os mesmos valores da [tabela ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/), então podemos pegar estes valores e manipulá-los de maneira "esperta" para fazer o que precisamos.

As letras maiúsculas estão no intervalo entre 65 e 90, e neste caso basta somar 32 para obter a respectiva letra minúscula (que por sua vez estão no intervalo entre 97 e 122, e por isso basta subtrair 96 para obter a respectiva posição desta no alfabeto). Se quiser que o algoritmo não seja *case insensitive*, basta remover o primeiro `if`.

Lembre-se que estou considerando que quando o caractere não for uma letra, coloco o valor zero. Mas se quiser ignorar estes caracteres, basta retirar o bloco `else`.

No caso acima eu usei um array para guardar as posições e depois juntei tudo com `join`. Mas você também poderia criar uma string diretamente e ir concatenando tudo diretamente nela:

```js
let frase = "Birulei Nau";
let posicoes = '';
for (let i = 0; i < frase.length; i++) {
    let c = frase.codePointAt(i);
    // se for letra maiúscula, converte para minúscula
    if (65 <= c && c <= 90) c+= 32;
    if (97 <= c && c <= 122) {
        posicoes += (c - 96);
    } else {
        posicoes += 0; // não é letra de A a Z, usar zero
    }
}
console.log(posicoes);
```

[Fiz alguns testes](https://jsbench.me/nck6cihbaz/2) e as soluções acima se mostraram mais rápidas do que usar `indexOf`. Claro que para poucas strings pequenas a diferença será insignificante, e talvez tudo isso não passe de [micro-otimização](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/99445), mas de qualquer forma fica aí a alternativa.

Answer (score 3):

Para substituir a letra pela posição do alfabeto, basta obter a posição da letra no Array com o método `indexOf` e somar `+1` já que os elementos em um Array começam na posição zero.

Para também ficar mais organizado seu código, você pode transformar o seu Array de letras em uma string única, pois strings também são sequências assim como Arrays. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
const alfabeto = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; 

function obterPosicao(letra){
    return alfabeto.indexOf(letra) + 1;
}
```

Para substituir as letras de uma frase pelas posições, basta transformar a string num Array, transformar cada letra em posições usando a função `obterPosicao` com o método `map` e depois juntar tudo em uma string novamente com o `join`. Veja como ficaria:

```
function substituiLetras(frase){
    frase = frase.split("");
    frase = frase.map(obterPosicao);
    frase = frase.join("");
    return frase;
}
```

O que o método `map` faz é retornar um novo Array com os valores retornados de uma função *callback* (no caso a função é `obterPosicao`) passando como parâmetro os elementos atuais do Array.

Já o método `join` serve para retornar uma string com todos os elementos do Array separados por um *separator* (no caso o separador é uma string vazia).

Comment: Certo, eu acho que entendi. Vou testar esses códigos. Obrigado JeanExtreme002!

Answer (score 1):

Pela forma com que está o teu código pode ser optimizado por questões como a utilização de map, mas o principal, nunca utilizar caracteres especiais, principalmente em nomes de variáveis, constantes e/ou funções. Segue um exemplo seguindo o teu código original:

```js
const frase = "Birulei Nau" // frase de teste

const alfabeto = [, "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];

const posiçãoLetra = []; // variável com a posição das letras do alfabeto

function encontraPosicao(letra) { // essa função encontra e preenche o array posiçãoLetra com as respectivas posições das letras do alfabeto.
  alfabeto.map((i, j) => {
    if (i === letra.toString().toLocaleLowerCase()) {
      return j;
    }
  })
}

encontraPosicao(alfabeto);


function substituiLetra(frase) {

  frase.split('').map((i, j) => {
    console.log(encontraPosicao(i));
  })

}

substituiLetra(frase);
```

Onde, em cada caso do loop de repetição, ele verifica se a posição do array se refere a uma letra idêntica a letra em que está como parâmetro na chamada da função, devolvendo assim o número de repetições (número da letra).