# Código não funciona como esperado

Tags: python, python-3.x

Meu código deveria ler nome e peso usando uma lista auxiliar e jogando os dados para uma lista principal. No final, ele gera um resultado do maior e menor peso com o nome das pessoas que possuem esses pesos.

O problema é que ele está substituindo a variável `menor` por um peso maior, que deveria ir para o `if` que atribui a variável `maior` ao peso e não no `if` abaixo. Além disso, depois do terceiro resultado ele não usa mais os `if`'s, o que é bem estranho.

Comentei algumas linhas que estava usando para *debugar*. Segue o código:

```
cadastro = []
dados = list()

while True:

    dados.append(input('Digite o nome: '))
    dados.append(input('Digite o peso: '))
    # print(dados[1])

    if len(cadastro) == 0:
        maior = menor = dados[1]

    else:

        if dados[1] > maior:
            maior = dados[1]
            # print(f'Função maior funcionando. {maior} {menor}')

        elif dados[1] < menor:
            menor = dados[1]
            # print(f'Função menor funcionando. {menor} {maior}')

    cadastro.append(dados.copy())
    dados.clear()
    resp = ' '

    while resp not in 'SN':
        resp = input('Você quer continuar? [S/N] ').strip().upper()[0]

    if resp == 'N':
        break

print(f'Ao todo você cadastrou {len(cadastro)} pessoas.')
print(f'O maior peso cadastrado foi {maior} de: ', end='')

for (nome, peso) in cadastro:
    if peso == maior:
        print(f'{nome}', end=' ')

print(f'O menor peso cadastrado foi {menor} de: ', end='')

for (nome, peso) in cadastro:
    if peso == menor:
        print(f'{nome}', end=' ')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O único erro que eu vi no código foi tratar o input do peso como String.

Demonstrado na linha **dados.append(int(input('Digite o peso: ')))**

```
cadastro = []
dados = list()

while True:

    dados.append(input('Digite o nome: '))
    **dados.append(int(input('Digite o peso: ')))**
    # print(dados[1])

    if len(cadastro) == 0:
        maior = menor = dados[1]

    else:

        if dados[1] > maior:
            maior = dados[1]
        # print(f'Função maior funcionando. {maior} {menor}')

        elif dados[1] < menor:
            menor = dados[1]
            # print(f'Função menor funcionando. {menor} {maior}')

    cadastro.append(dados.copy())
    dados.clear()
    resp = ' '

    while resp not in 'SN':
        resp = input('Você quer continuar? [S/N] ').strip().upper()[0]

    if resp == 'N':
        break

print(f'Ao todo você cadastrou {len(cadastro)} pessoas.')
print(f'O maior peso cadastrado foi {maior} de: ', end='')

for (nome, peso) in cadastro:
    if peso == maior:
        print(f'{nome}', end=' ')

print(f'O menor peso cadastrado foi {menor} de: ', end='')

for (nome, peso) in cadastro:
    if peso == menor:
        print(f'{nome}', end=' ')
```

Answer (score 2):

Você não informou os dados que usou para testar, mas o problema *provavelmente* ocorre porque o peso deveria ser um número, mas no código você manipula-o como string (já que [`input` retorna uma string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input)).

O problema de comparar strings é que, mesmo se só tiverem dígitos, [elas são comparadas lexicograficamente](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types). Isso quer dizer que a string `'2'` é considerada "maior" que a string `'10'`:

```
print('2' > '10') # imprime "True"
```

Eis o trecho relevante da [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types) que explica esse comportamento:

> *Lexicographical ordering for strings uses the Unicode code point number to order individual characters*

Ou seja, a ordem lexicográfica leva em conta os *Unicode code points* de cada caractere (para entender melhor o que é um *code point*, sugiro começar [por aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/394834/112052)). Mas basicamente, cada caractere possui um código numérico associado (pense no Unicode como uma extensão da [tabela ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) - e que fique claro que essa é uma simplificação **bem** grosseira), e ao comparar strings, o valor desse código (que é o *code point*) é usado para determinar o que é "maior" ou "menor".

No caso, o [*code point* do caractere `'2'`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/32/index.htm) é maior que [o do caractere `'1'`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/31/index.htm), por isso a string `'2'` é considerada "maior" que a string `'10'`. Funciona da mesma forma que uma comparação entre as strings `'b'` e `'ac'`. Como o `b` é "maior" que o `a` (o [*code point* do caractere `b`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/62/index.htm) é maior que [o do caractere `a`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/61/index.htm)), então lexicograficamente `'b' > 'ac'` - ou seja, em uma ordenação de strings, o `'b'` viria depois de `'ac'`, assim como o `'2'` viria depois de `'10'`:

```
lista = [ '2', '10' ]
print(sorted(lista)) # ['10', '2']

lista = [ 'b', 'ac' ]
print(sorted(lista)) # ['ac', 'b']
```

<sup>*[Veja aqui](https://ideone.com/ANox4x) este código rodando*</sup>

Enfim, ao comparar pesos desta maneira, como strings, pode ocorrer a situação que você descreveu: um peso com valor numérico menor (por exemplo, `2`) é considerado maior que outro (como o `10`) porque os dados estão como strings, e não como números.

---

Se quer levar em conta os valores numéricos (e não os code points dos caracteres da string) para fazer as comparações (e acredito que seja isso que você quer, já que estamos falando de pesos), você deve converter o peso para número, usando [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) (caso só possa ter valores inteiros) ou [`float()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float) (se puder ter casas decimais). Você também pode capturar o [`ValueError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError), que ocorre caso não seja digitado um número, e pedir que digite novamente. Ficaria assim:

```
while True:
    try:
        peso = int(input('Digite o peso: '))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('Peso deve ser um número')
```

<sup>*Inclusive, na [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) tem um exemplo igual a este.*</sup>

Ou seja, enquanto não for digitado um número, continua pedindo que digite novamente. Assim você garante que o peso será um número e que as comparações sejam feitas corretamente, levando em conta o valor numérico.

---

Outro detalhe é que talvez você não precise guardar tudo em uma lista, se o objetivo é somente obter o maior e menor valor. Uma opção seria manter um contador de cadastros e atualizar o maior e menor valores diretamente, sem precisar guardar em uma lista:

```
cont = 0
while True:
    nome = input('Digite o nome: ')
    while True:
        try:
            peso = int(input('Digite o peso: '))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print('Peso deve ser um número')

    if cont == 0:
        maior_peso = menor_peso = peso
        nome_maior = nome_menor = nome
    else:
        if peso > maior_peso:
            maior_peso = peso
            nome_maior = nome
        elif peso < menor_peso:
            menor_peso = peso
            nome_menor = nome

    cont += 1
    resp = ' '
    while resp not in 'SN':
        resp = input('Você quer continuar? [S/N] ').strip().upper()[0]
    if resp == 'N':
        break

print(f'Ao todo você cadastrou {cont} pessoas.')
print(f'O maior peso cadastrado foi {maior_peso} de: {nome_maior}')
print(f'O menor peso cadastrado foi {menor_peso} de: {nome_menor}')
```

**OBS:** A diferença para o seu código é que este só imprime um dos nomes em caso de empate. Já o *loop* que você fez imprime todos os nomes, caso tenha mais de uma pessoa com o peso mínimo ou máximo. Neste caso, eu até entendo o motivo de ter que guardar tudo em uma lista.

---

Se quer guardar os cadastros em uma lista, não precisa de duas listas como você fez (e insere em uma para logo depois remover, é uma complicação à toa). Bastaria adicionar o cadastro dentro do *loop*, assim:

```
cadastros = [] # Obs: usar [] e list() dá no mesmo, ambos criam uma lista vazia
while True:
    nome = input('Digite o nome: ')
    while True:
        try:
            peso = int(input('Digite o peso: '))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print('Peso deve ser um número')

    if len(cadastros) == 0:
        maior_peso = menor_peso = peso
    else:
        if peso > maior_peso:
            maior_peso = peso
        elif peso < menor_peso:
            menor_peso = peso

    cadastros.append((nome, peso))
    resp = ' '
    while resp not in 'SN':
        resp = input('Você quer continuar? [S/N] ').strip().upper()[0]
    if resp == 'N':
        break

print(f'Ao todo você cadastrou {len(cadastros)} pessoas.')

print(f'O maior peso cadastrado foi {maior_peso} de: ', end='')    
for (nome, peso) in cadastros:
    if peso == maior_peso:
        print(f'{nome}', end=' ')

print(f'O menor peso cadastrado foi {menor_peso} de: ', end='')    
for (nome, peso) in cadastros:
    if peso == menor_peso:
        print(f'{nome}', end=' ')
```

Se bem que a parte final é meio repetitiva, daria para simplificar criando uma função:

```
def encontrar_nomes_por_peso(cadastros, peso_busca, descricao):
    print(f'O {descricao} peso cadastrado foi {peso_busca} de: ', end='')

    for (nome, peso) in cadastros:
        if peso == peso_busca:
            print(f'{nome}', end=' ')
    print()

encontrar_nomes_por_peso(cadastros, maior_peso, 'maior')
encontrar_nomes_por_peso(cadastros, menor_peso, 'menor')
```

Answer (score 0):

cara , eu usei lista de dicionario..

`cadastro = []
while True:
    nome = input('Digite o nome: ')
    peso = int(input('Digite o peso: ')) 
    cadastro.append({'nome':nome,'peso':peso})
    resp = input('Você quer continuar? [S/N] ')
    if resp.upper() == 'N':
        break`

print(f'Ao todo você cadastrou {len(cadastro)} pessoas.')
lista_pesos = [x['peso'] for x in cadastro]
lista_pesos.sort()
peso_maior = lista_pesos[-1]
peso_menor = lista_pesos[0]

maior = [ x for x in cadastro if x['peso']== peso_maior][0]
menor = [ x for x in cadastro if x['peso']== peso_menor][0]

print(f'O maior peso cadastrado foi do {maior["nome"]} com {maior["peso"]}'   )
print(f'O menor peso cadastrado foi do {menor["nome"]} com {menor["peso"]}',  )