# Guardar nomes lidos em uma lista e escolher aleatoriamente um deles

Tags: python, lista

Como faço para, dentre os alunos que eu digitar, ele sortear um dentro do `range`?

No código abaixo ele não sorteia, me retorna apenas o último nome:

```
from random import choice
for c in range(1, 4):
    aluno = str(input(f'Nome do {c}º aluno: '))
    lista = choice(aluno)
print(lista)
```

Comment: Você não está criando uma lista de nomes; você está sobrescrevendo o nome 3 vezes. Também não faz sentido você sortear dentro do laço de repetição, pois ainda não haverá todos os valores possíveis, o sorteio deveria ser fora. Recomendo fazer um teste de mesa para indentificar essas falhas de lógica nos seus códigos.

Comment: E sei que está sobrescrevendo e mesmo que não tenha lógica, só estou testando possibilidades pois estou começando agora. Eu gostaria de saber como ficaria o código para tal objetivo, seja criando uma lista através do range ou fazendo o ele sortear sem precisar de uma lista.

Comment: Você já estudou listas? Se sim, como tentou fazer?

Comment: Esqueceu de criar a lista. Abaixo resolvei esta questão com bastante clareza.

Answer (score 2):

Segundo a documentação, [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) recebe uma sequência e retorna um dos elementos desta sequência (escolhido aleatoriamente).

No caso, você está passando a variável `aluno`, que é uma string, e [strings também são sequências](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str), sendo que cada caractere da mesma é um elemento (na verdade cada *code point* é um elemento, entenda a diferença entre caractere e code point [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/396555/112052)).

Então na verdade, ao usar `choice` passando uma string, o resultado é um dos seus caracteres:

```
from random import choice
print(choice('abcdefghi')) # vai imprimir apenas uma das letras
```

---

O que você precisa é criar uma lista com os nomes dos alunos, e só depois escolher um dos nomes aleatoriamente. Então não use `choice` dentro do *loop*. Use o *loop* para construir a lista, e só depois faça a escolha:

```
from random import choice

lista = [] # lista começa vazia
for c in range(1, 4):
    aluno = input(f'Nome do {c}º aluno: ')
    lista.append(aluno) # adiciona o aluno na lista

aluno_escolhido = choice(lista)
print(aluno_escolhido) # escolhe um dos alunos da lista
```

Outro detalhe é que [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) já retorna uma string, então não precisa fazer `str(input(...))`.

Por fim, pode simplificar um pouco mais, pois se só quer adicionar o aluno na lista e nada mais, não precisa da variável `aluno`. O mesmo vale para `aluno_escolhido`: se só vai imprimir e nada mais, também não precisa da variável.

```
from random import choice

lista = [] # lista começa vazia
for c in range(1, 4):
    lista.append(input(f'Nome do {c}º aluno: ')) # adiciona o aluno na lista

print(choice(lista)) # escolhe um dos alunos da lista
```

---

Outra forma de construir a lista é usando uma [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=list%20comprehension#list-comprehensions), bem mais sucinta e [*pythônica*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192343/112052):

```
from random import choice

lista = [ input(f'Nome do {c}º aluno: ') for c in range(1, 4) ]
print(choice(lista)) # escolhe um dos alunos da lista
```

Comment: Exatamente isso que eu queria,perfeito, muito obrigado!

Comment: @GlebsonSantos Se a resposta resolveu o seu problema, vc pode aceitá-la, [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema. E quando tiver 15 pontos, [**vc também poderá votar**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) em todas as respostas que achou úteis.

Answer (score 0):

O problema do seu código é que você `esqueceu` de criar a lista.

Uma das formas corretas de se resolver este problema é utilizando o algoritmo que implementei, logo abaixo.

```
from random import choice

# Captura e trata a quantidade de nomes a ser inseridos no sorteio
while True:
    try:
        n = int(input('Desejas inserir quantos nomes no sorteio? '))
        # Para haver sorteio são necessários, pelo menos, "2" elementos.
        if n <= 1:
            print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite valores maiores que "1"!\033[m')
        else:
            break
    except:
        print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas números inteiros!\033[m')

# Cria a lista de nomes.
nomes = list()
for c in range(1, n + 1):
    nome = input(f'Digite o {c}º nome: ')
    # insere cada nome na lista.
    nomes.append(nome)

# Sorteia apenas "1" nome da lista.
sorteado = choice(nomes)
print(f'\033[32mO nome sorteado é: {sorteado}\033[m')
```

Veja o funcionamento do algoritmo no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/join/mfetctwv-solkarped)

Note, que este algoritmo também realiza o tratamento dos valores capturados pelo input.

Perceba também que o algoritmo utiliza o método `"choice"` da classe `"random"` para realizar o sorteio.