# Como converter Java source string em HEX para Unicode para incorporar na HTML?

Tags: javascript, css

Como converter usando JavaScript:

O tipo **Java source string**: `\u900` para **unicode**: `&#x900;`

Hoje eu tenho o seguinte elemento HTML:

```
<i class="icon-zoom-out"></i>
```

E a classe do CSS:

```
@font-face {
        font-family: 'iconcombo';
        src:
          url("#{$PATH_FONTS}iconcombo.ttf?g5kz9z") format("truetype");
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
        font-display: block;
      }
      
      [class^='icon-'],
      [class*=' icon-'] {
        /* use !important to prevent issues with browser extensions that change fonts */
        font-family: 'iconcombo' !important;
        speak: none;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-variant: normal;
        text-transform: none;
        line-height: 1;
      
        /* Better Font Rendering =========== */
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
      }

.icon-zoom-out:before {
    content: '\e900';
}
```

A ideia é que eu não precise passar a classe no pseudo-elemento before, mas incorporar diretamente:

```
<i>&#x900;</i>
```

**Sugestão:**

```
function convertHexToUnicode(param) {
  //aqui viria o método que faz a conversão
  return resultConvertUnicode;
}    

var icon = {
'zoom-out': '\ue900',
'zoom-in': '\ue901',
'zip-archive': '\ue902',
 zip: '\ue903',
 yen: '\ue904',
 ...
}

function getIcon(className, element) {
    var resultUnicode = convertHexToUnicode(icon[className]);
    element.innerHTML = '<i>'+resultUnicode+'</i>';
}
```

Comment: E como você sugere que isso seja feito? Você tem um objeto que mapeia um nome de ícone para o seu respectivo Unicode _code point_? Acho que vale [edit] a pergunta para acrescentar mais detalhes.

Comment: Eu não imagino como, se eu tivesse ideia, não estaria como uma pergunta. O mapeamento não importa neste momento, porque um método genérico poderia resolver todas as estruturas que virão, já que se trata de um mesmo tipo.

Comment: Veja que não é uma [dúvida incomum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25731219/how-to-convert-a-java-source-code-string-to-html-entity-hex-string-in-java)

Comment: P.S. Editei, e acrescentei mais detalhes da sugestão, como vc sugeriu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você já possui um mapa que cria uma relação entre um nome de ícone e o seu respectivo código de *escape* para o Unicode em JavaScript, o que irá criar um mapa de nome de ícone para um determinado caractere com base no seu *code point*.

Desse modo, basta criar um método que captura novamente o *code point* de um determinado caractere e o insere em uma [entidade HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity).

```js
const icons = {
  'zoom-out': '\ue900',
  'zoom-in': '\ue901',
  'zip-archive': '\ue902',
  'zip': '\ue903',
  'yen': '\ue904',
  
  // Exemplo para demonstrar:
  'happy': '\ud83d\ude03'
};

function charToHTMLEntity(char) {
  const codePoint = char.codePointAt(0);
  return `&#${codePoint};`;
}

console.log(charToHTMLEntity(icons.happy)); // &#128515;
document.body.innerHTML = charToHTMLEntity(icons.happy);
```

O método [`codePointAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/codePointAt) retorna um número natural que representa um Unicode *code point* em uma determinada posição. A partir dele, cria-se uma entidade HTML em seu formato decimal.

Vale citar que o exemplo `happy` possui "duas sequências de escape", isto é, uma sequência com dois *code units*. Isso na verdade se chama *[surrogate pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Code_points_from_U+010000_to_U+10FFFF)* e é usado para escapar, no JavaScript, caracteres acima do Unicode *code point* U+FFFF.

Note, no entanto, que:

> O tipo Java source string: `\u900` para unicode: `&#x900;`.

Está errado. Primeiro que "Java" é uma coisa e "JavaScript" é outra. E, na verdade, o primeiro (`\u900`) é uma sequência que escapa, em JavaScript, um Unicode *code-point* para o seu respectivo caractere. O segundo (`&#x900`) não é "Unicode", mas sim uma entidade HTML em formato hexadecimal. Essa entidade pode ser definida de modo decimal ou hexadecimal, veja:

```html
<!-- Forma decimal -->
&#128515;

<!-- Forma hexadecimal equivalente. 
     Note o `x`, que a denota. -->
&#x1f603;
```

Para saber mais sobre essa terminologia relacionada a caracteres e ao Unicode, leia [esta excelente resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/396555/69296).