# Meu algoritmo gera um Hash SHA512 apresenta um resultado não esperado

Tags: c#, algoritmo

Tenho a seguinte string:

```
<Rps><InfDeclaracaoPrestacaoServicoId="1"><Rps><IdentificacaoRps><Numero>4</Numero><Serie>aaa</Serie><Tipo>1</Tipo></IdentificacaoRps><DataEmissao>2019-07-08</DataEmissao><Status>1</Status></Rps><Competencia>2019-07-08</Competencia><Servico><Valores><ValorServicos>2358.77</ValorServicos><ValorDeducoes>0</ValorDeducoes><ValorPis>0</ValorPis><ValorCofins>0</ValorCofins><ValorInss>0</ValorInss><ValorIr>0</ValorIr><ValorCsll>0</ValorCsll><OutrasRetencoes>0</OutrasRetencoes><Aliquota>0</Aliquota><DescontoIncondicionado>0</DescontoIncondicionado><DescontoCondicionado>0</DescontoCondicionado></Valores><IssRetido>1</IssRetido><ResponsavelRetencao>1</ResponsavelRetencao><ItemListaServico>07.02</ItemListaServico><Discriminacao>TESTANDORPSDISCRIMINAO</Discriminacao><CodigoMunicipio>3526902</CodigoMunicipio></Servico><Prestador><CpfCnpj><Cnpj>88888888888888</Cnpj></CpfCnpj><InscricaoMunicipal>123456</InscricaoMunicipal></Prestador><TomadorServico><IdentificacaoTomador><CpfCnpj><Cnpj>55555555555555</Cnpj></CpfCnpj></IdentificacaoTomador><RazaoSocial>Dorotheo</RazaoSocial><Endereco><Endereco>RuaJapo</Endereco><Numero>2</Numero><Complemento>TESTERPS</Complemento><Bairro>Jaragua</Bairro><CodigoMunicipio>3550704</CodigoMunicipio><Uf>SP</Uf><Cep>11600318</Cep></Endereco><Contato><Telefone>12345678901</Telefone><Email>teste@teste.com</Email></Contato><AtualizaTomador>2</AtualizaTomador><TomadorExterior>2</TomadorExterior></TomadorServico><InformacoesComplementares>TESTANDORPS</InformacoesComplementares></InfDeclaracaoPrestacaoServico></Rps>TLXX4JN38KXTRNSEAJYYEA==
```

E devo obter como Hash:

```
61AEC2215401D0099D85D70A56D72949860CA07C55620C37B49F8F2DA7CF9A671AFAC6C96D95BD74F9304B97CEBC6A90CDF9F7134B2A5F41A12629F7D6111BA1
```

(Podem verificar [nesse site](https://www.convertstring.com/pt_PT/Hash/SHA512))

Fiz a seguinte função :

```
public string HashIntegridade(string Dados)
{
    SHA512 shaM = SHA512.Create();
   
    var hashIntegridadeBytes = shaM.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Dados));
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(hashIntegridadeBytes);      
}
```

Já testei diferentes variações dessa função, tentando usar `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes` e outros tipos de codificação e nunca obtenho o resultado esperado.

O resultado que estou obtendo `a��!T\u0001�\t���\nV�)I�\f�|Ub\f7���-�Ϛg\u001a���m��t�0K�μj����\u0013K*_A�&)��\u0011\u001b�`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O [método `ComputeHash`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.computehash?view=net-5.0) retorna um array de bytes.

Ao usar `Encoding.UTF8.GetString`, você está tentando transformar estes bytes em um texto, usando a codificação UTF-8 (*[leitura relacionada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/394834/112052), caso queira entender em mais detalhes*). Mas não é isso que deve ser feito, pois os bytes resultantes de um hash não vão necessariamente formar um texto coerente (se for, é por coincidência).

O que o site que você testou retorna é uma representação em hexadecimal dos bytes. No caso, o primeiro byte é `61` (o valor 61 em hexadecimal, que em UTF-8 se transforma na letra `a`, mas isso é irrelevante, pois um hash resulta em bytes e não em texto, se esse byte corresponde ou não a um caractere é algo totalmente circunstancial). O segundo byte é `AE` (que em UTF-8 não é reconhecido), e assim por diante.

Enfim, para resolver, basta transformar o array de bytes em uma string contendo a sua representação em hexadecimal. Uma opção é usar `BitConverter`:

```
public string HashIntegridade(string Dados)
{
    SHA512 shaM = SHA512.Create();
    
    var hashIntegridadeBytes = shaM.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Dados));
    return BitConverter.ToString(hashIntegridadeBytes).Replace("-","");
}
```

Ou use um `StringBuilder` e vá convertendo os bytes um a um:

```
public string HashIntegridade(string Dados)
{
    SHA512 shaM = SHA512.Create();
    
    var hashIntegridadeBytes = shaM.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Dados));
    StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(hashIntegridadeBytes.Length * 2);
    foreach (byte b in hashIntegridadeBytes)
        hex.AppendFormat("{0:X2}", b);
    return hex.ToString();
}
```