# Por que a resposta de request HTTP não reconhece caracteres especiais?

Tags: html, python, request, python-requests, beautifulsoup

Por que quando eu faço um request usando BeautifulSoup em Python, a minha resposta não considera caracteres latinos?

Código:

```py
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
req = requests.post(url= f"https://www.linkcorreios.com.br/?id=LE132696585SE")
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text,'html.parser')
texto = soup.find('ul', {'class': 'linha_status m-0'}).text
print(req)
print(texto)
```

Resposta:

```
<Response [200]>
Status: Objeto em trÃ¢nsito - por favor aguarde
Data  : 29/04/2021 | Hora: 10:29
Origem: Unidade de LogÃ­stica Integrada - Curitiba / PR
Destino: Unidade de Tratamento - Cajamar / SP
```

Estou usando o VSCode com Python 3.9.4

Answer (score 2):

Resumindo, é um problema de *encoding* (se quer entender a fundo o que é um *encoding*, [leia aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/394834/112052)).

Mas basicamente, toda a informação trafegada vai e vem na forma de bytes, que são transformados em texto e vice-versa. E existem várias formas de converter bytes de/para texto (vários *encodings* diferentes), e esse tipo de problema acontece ao tentar usar um *encoding* quando na verdade foi usado outro (por exemplo, se a resposta foi convertida para bytes usando um *encoding*, mas você tenta converter esses bytes para texto usando outro *encoding*).

Na documentação do módulo `requests` podemos ver [aqui](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content) o seguinte:

> *When you make a request, Requests makes educated guesses about the encoding of the response based on the HTTP headers.*

E [aqui](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#encodings):

> *When you receive a response, Requests makes a guess at the encoding to use for decoding the response when you access the `Response.text` attribute.*

Ou seja, ao ser feita uma requisição, o `requests` tenta adivinhar o *encoding* da resposta, baseado nos headers HTTP. Então ao acessar o atributo `text` da resposta, será usado esse *encoding* para converter os bytes em texto. Mas o mesmo link acima ainda afirma:

> *The only time Requests will not do this is if no explicit charset is present in the HTTP headers and the Content-Type header contains text. In this situation, RFC 2616 specifies that the default charset must be ISO-8859-1.*

Ou seja, se não houver um *charset* especificado nos headers HTTP, e o `Content-Type` contém `text`, o *encoding* será setado para ISO-8859-1. Podemos ver que esse é exatamente o caso, imprimindo os headers da resposta:

```py
response = requests.post('https://www.linkcorreios.com.br/?id=LE132696585SE')
print(response.headers)
```

A saída foi:

```py
{'Date': 'Wed, 23 Jun 2021 11:55:38 GMT', 'Server': 'Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)', 'X-Powered-By': 'PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.21', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Content-Length': '5090', 'Keep-Alive': 'timeout=5, max=100', 'Connection': 'Keep-Alive', 'Content-Type': 'text/html'}
```

Podemos ver que o `Content-Type` é `text/html` (ou seja, contém `text`) e não há um *charset* explícito em nenhum dos headers. Por isso o *encoding* usado será ISO-8859-1, o que pode ser confirmado assim:

```py
response = requests.post('https://www.linkcorreios.com.br/?id=LE132696585SE')
print(response.encoding) # ISO-8859-1
```

Portanto, ao tentar acessar o atributo `text`, os bytes foram convertidos para texto usando-se o *encoding* ISO-8859-1.

Mas como vimos, a página não está em ISO-8859-1, senão os acentos seriam mostrados corretamente.

---

A solução é simples: em vez de passar o `text` da resposta, passe o `content`:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.post('https://www.linkcorreios.com.br/?id=LE132696585SE')

# *** Em vez de response.text, use response.content ***
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
#                             ^^^^^^^

texto = soup.find('ul', {'class': 'linha_status m-0'}).get_text()
print(response)
print(texto)
```

Assim, o Beautiful Soup lerá os "bytes brutos" (em vez de um texto que foi decodificado usando o *encoding* errado), e ele saberá lidar com isso, convertendo esses bytes em texto (mais detalhes [aqui](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?highlight=encoding#encodings)). Com isso, os acentos serão mostrados corretamente.