# Diferença entre os métodos casefold() e lower()

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Me deparei com o método `casefold`, e até onde eu percebi ele faz exatamente a mesma coisa que o `lower`. Tem algum exemplo da diferença entre os dois? E a utilidade desse método `casefold`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A diferença é que cada um usa um algoritmo distinto para fazer suas conversões (apesar de muitas vezes darem o mesmo resultado).

Segundo a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower), `lower` faz o seguinte:

> *Return a copy of the string with all the cased characters `[4]` converted to lowercase*

E o `[4]` acima é um link para [a definição de "*cased character*"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#id15):

> *Cased characters are those with general category property being one of "Lu" (Letter, uppercase), "Ll" (Letter, lowercase), or "Lt" (Letter, titlecase).*

E como essas categorias abrangem vários caracteres (não apenas ASCII, ver mais informações sobre essas categorias [aqui](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Lu/index.htm), [aqui](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Ll/index.htm) e [aqui](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Lt/index.htm)), `lower` converte qualquer caractere Unicode que esteja nestas categorias para sua versão em minúscula, caso exista (se não existir, o mesmo caractere é retornado). Por exemplo, a letra grega `Δ` (Delta maiúsculo, [code point U+0394](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0394/index.htm), portanto um caractere não-ASCII), funciona perfeitamente com `lower`:

```py
s = 'Δ'

print(s.lower())
print(s.casefold())
print(s.lower() == s.casefold())
```

O código acima imprime:

```
δ
δ
True
```

Repare que `casefold` também deu o mesmo resultado de `lower`. Isso vai acontecer para muitos caracteres, mas existe uma diferença. A [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold) diz que `casefold` é similar a `lower`, porém é mais "agressivo" ao eliminar "*all case distinctions*".

**E esta é a diferença: o algoritmo usado por cada um**. A documentação diz que `casefold` usa o algoritmo de *casefolding*, e `lower` usa o algoritmo de *lowercasing*, ambos descritos pelo Unicode.

---

## A diferença

As documentações de ambos os métodos citam a seção 3.13 do Unicode. Se verificarmos o [respectivo documento](https://www.unicode.org/versions/latest/ch03.pdf), veremos a diferença entre eles.

O algoritmo em si é bem complicado, com definições que se estendem por várias páginas, mas o ponto é que os algoritmos de *lowercasing* e *casefolding* usam regras diferentes. Claro que para muitos casos o resultado é o mesmo, mas existem diferenças importantes que justificam a existência desses dois métodos distintos.

Um caso clássico é o caractere `ß` ([LATIN SMALL LETTER SHARP S](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00df/index.htm)), que não é modificado por `lower` por já ser uma letra minúscula (ele faz parte da [categoria "Letter, lowercase"](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Ll/list.htm)), mas é modificado por `casefold` (o resultado é `ss`):

```py
s = 'ß'
print(s.islower()) # True
print(s.lower()) # ß
print(s.casefold()) # ss
```

O fato de usar um algoritmo diferente (e mais complicado) faz com que `casefold` **nem sempre retorne caracteres minúsculos**. Por exemplo, para o caractere `Ꮛ` ([CHEROKEE LETTER QUV](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/13CB/index.htm)), que é uma letra maiúscula, `casefold` retorna sua versão em maiúscula:

```py
s = 'Ꮛ'
print(s.isupper()) # True (é maiúscula)
# casefold retorna a versão maiúscula do caractere
print(s.upper() == s.casefold()) # True
print(s.lower() == s.casefold()) # False
```

Estas são as diferenças. Dependendo do seu cenário, elas podem ou não serem revelantes (por exemplo, se está lidando apenas com textos em português, `lower` é mais que suficiente).

Vale lembrar que a documentação do Python diz que "*Casefolded strings may be used for caseless matching*" (`casefold` pode ser usado para comparações *case insensitive*), enquanto que na documentação de `lower` não há menção a isso (mas novamente, dependendo do caso, `lower` pode ser usado sem problemas para tal finalidade).

O documento do Unicode também diz algo similar:

> *the main purpose of case folding is to contribute to caseless matching of strings, whereas the main purpose of case conversion is to put strings into a particular cased form.*

Ou seja, *casefolding* é o mais recomendado para comparações *case insensitive*, enquanto os outros algoritmos (*lowercasing*, *uppercasing*, etc) são mais apropriados para converter a string para uma determinada forma (e novamente, claro que dependendo do caso, *lowercasing* já seja suficiente).

Enfim, o importante é saber as diferenças, e se/como isso afetará os seus sistemas.

Comment: A [Seção 5.18](https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode14.0.0/ch05.pdf) (Case Mappings) do Unicode também traz mais detalhes interessantes.

Answer (score 1):

[`lower()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) foi criado nas primeiras versões de Python e está preparando para fazer a operação em um texto em ASCII ([Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45745661/221800)). Em nenhum momento está dito aqui que só funciona com ASCII, com Unicode o resultado poderá não ser o esperado.

A evolução levou as pessoas usarem Unicode já que permite combinações mais complexas e pode trabalhar com muito mais formas de formar palavras e ter letras. Para fazer operações em texto que considerem Unicode precisa de funções que consigam entender isto, sem quebrar a compatibilidade com o que já existia. Para isto foi criada a [`casefold()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold).

Então você tem que saber qual é o formato que está usando o seu texto e considerar se faz diferença usar um ou outro de acordo com as regras de cada cultura.

Exemplo onde não faz diferente porque a função básica entender o ASCII estendido e depois quando usa caractere que não faz parte do ASCII:

```
print("FORMATAÇÃO".lower())
print("FORMATAÇÃO".casefold())
print("der Fluß".lower())
print("der Fluß".casefold())
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/txcUOo). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/swoqqhxffb-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/String/LowerCasefold.py).

Comment: Ambos os métodos conseguem lidar com Unicode. `"Γ".lower()` é igual a `"Γ".casefold()`. A real diferença é que `lower` implementa o algoritmo **toLowercase** e `casefold` o algoritmo **toCasefold**, ambos especificados no [capítulo 3.13](https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode14.0.0/ch03.pdf) do padrão Unicode. Em linhas gerais, `casefold` vai mexer com mais caracteres do que `lower` (e o exemplo com ß revela justamente uma caso onde isso ocorre), mas não há uma divisão ASCII/Unicode propriamente dita.

Comment: @sourcream cite uma fonte, porque a documentação diz o contrário.

Comment: a documentação do [`lower`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) (que você já citou na sua resposta) e do [`casefold`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold) dizem exatamente isso que eu falei: *The lowercasing /casefolding algorithm is described in section 3.13 of the Unicode Standard.* O link para o capítulo 3.13 está no meu comentário anterior e lá você poderá encontrar os algoritmos. E você não citou fonte do que você afirmou.

Comment: @sourcream lá fala do algoritmo, não do charset. Se fosse igual o resultado deveria ser igual, o `lower()` só tem 256 possibilidades, que é o que o ASCII estendido permite, o Unicode permite muito mais. Estude sobre o assunto. Comece por https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/394834/101.

Comment: E como você explica `"Γ".lower()` funcionar?

Comment: E como você explica o ß "não funcionar"? Se a sua "lógica" fizesse algum sentido então ambos funcionariam. Existem símbolos que não possuem maiúsculo e minúsculo, você não pode pegar qualquer coisa e usar como "prova" do que está falando, você tem que demonstrar porque deveria ser diferente. O lower de 1 é 1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmp0i.jpg. Se quer insistir nisso use alguma referência confiável, não o que você acha porque observou algo sem entender como funciona.

Comment: `"ß".lower()` não funciona porque ß já é uma letra minúscula. A versão maiúscula é ẞ e `"ẞ".lower()` funciona normalmente (e essa é mais uma evidência de que não tem nada a ver essa história de um servir para ASCII e o outro para Unicode). Não é da minha cabeça, é o que está descrito na documentação oficial.

Comment: @sourcream demonstre onde está escrito isso na documentação oficial.

Comment: "Casefolding is similar to lowercasing but more aggressive..." e "The lowercasing/casefolding algorithm is described in section 3.13 of the Unicode Standard". Se você ler a seção 3.13 do Unicode (leia, é curta), verá que são algoritmos diferentes para propósitos diferentes, o que acaba deixando o `casefold` "mais agressivo", mas, de novo, não é porque um é ASCII ou Unicode.

Comment: Eu quero que você diga onde na documentação diz o que você afirma, e onde minha resposta está errada para receber negativo.

Comment: Sua resposta sugere que `lower` é para ASCII e `casefold` para Unicode. Isso está errado, pois a diferença está nos algoritmos e não no charset.  A explicação dos algoritmos e suas diferenças está na Seção 3.13 do Unicode (está em inglês, se não entender, sugiro usar um tradutor). Outro erro foi usar uma letra já minúscula no seu exemplo. Veja também a resposta mais votada.

Comment: A documentação diz de maneira indireta. [`lower`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower): "*Return a copy of the string with all the **cased characters** `[4]` converted to lowercase*" **⟵** e esse `[4]` é um link para [a definição de "_cased character_"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#id15): "*Cased characters are those with general category property being one of “Lu” (Letter, uppercase), “Ll” (Letter, lowercase), or “Lt” (Letter, titlecase).*". E essas categorias Lu, Ll e Lt abrangem vários caracteres, inclusive não-ASCII.

Comment: Basta ver a lista de caracteres de cada categoria: [Lu](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Lu/list.htm), [Ll](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Ll/list.htm) e [Lt](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Lt/list.htm) - perceba que há inúmeros caracteres, que vão muito além do ASCII... Enfim, na [minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/544753/112052) eu detalho mais :-)

Comment: A sua interpretação é essa, minha resposta não sugere nada. Então não tenho mais o que falar, é sua intepretação não minha resposta. Ficou claro que seu comentário é em cima da sua interpretação e não da minha reposta, era só o que eu queria. Se você quer usar `lower(0` em Unicode fique à vontade, se der algo errado não reclame comigo, eu avisei. A minha resposta diz de forma direta, e a documentação dizendo de forma indireta e é melhor?

Comment: Outro erro aparente: "Para fazer operações em texto que considerem Unicode precisa de funções que consigam entender isto, sem quebrar a compatibilidade com o que já existia. Para isto foi criada a `casefold()`". Não achei referência nenhuma sobre esse histórico do `casefold` ter sido criado por causa disso. O que há é o que está na documentação oficial, que é que cada um implementa um algoritmo diferente (ambos compatíveis com Unicode),

Comment: Outro problema, que surgiu depois da edição: "Unicode o resultado poderá não ser o esperado.". Essa informação não tem fonte alguma e não consta na documentação oficial.

Comment: Hoje o algoritmo do objeto [str(unicodeobject) em python3](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/unicodeobject.c) implementado com base no padrão Unicode, mas se conferir o [str(stringobject) em python2](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.18/Python-2.7.18.tgz) vai encontrar uma tentativa de adaptação ao Unicode. Pesquisei bastante e achei a diferença, nessa [documentação](https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode14.0.0/ch03.pdf) deve ser a partir da página 151 e vai começar a fazer sentido para a divergência em questão a partir da página 154. Segue a tradução:

Comment: *...Case fold está relacionado à conversão de caixa. No entanto, o principal objetivo do case fold é
contribuir para a correspondência sem maiúsculas e minúsculas de strings, enquanto o principal objetivo da conversão de maiúsculas e minúsculas é
para colocar strings em uma forma de caixa específica.
O Default Case Folding não preserva as [formas de normalização](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize). Uma string em um formulário de normalização Unicode específico pode não estar nessa forma de normalização depois de ter sido feito case fold...*