# Pegando parte de um texto especifico usando python

Tags: python, regex

Preciso pegar todo o texto que está entre "pedidos de teste" até o próximo título "processos correspondente".

Criei o código abaixo tentando usar o regex, porém sem sucesso:

```py
import re

text = """
TEXTO ACIMA

PEDIDOS DE TESTE

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut 
labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris 
nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit 
esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, 
sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

PROCESSOS CORRESPONDENTE

On the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and 
demoralized by the charms of pleasure of the moment, so blinded by desire, that they cannot foresee 
the pain and trouble that are bound to ensue; and equal blame belongs to those who fail in their duty 
through weakness of will, which is the same as saying through shrinking from toil and pain. 
These cases are perfectly simple and easy to distinguish.

MAIS TEXTO"""

results = re.findall(r'^(?:PEDIDOS)?:PROCESSOS$',
                     text, re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)

for result in results:
    print(result)
```

No cenário real vou ler este texto em um arquivo txt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Um ponto que não ficou claro é que na pergunta é citado que os delimitadores são "PEDIDOS DE TESTE" e "PROCESSOS CORRESPONDENTE", mas na [sua resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/568233/112052) você colocou "Pedidos" e "Reembolso". De qualquer forma, nesta resposta coloquei os exemplos com "Pedidos" e "Reembolso", mas se for o caso, bastaria trocar os parâmetros indicados abaixo (por exemplo, `extrair_trechos(texto, 'PEDIDOS DE TESTE', 'PROCESSOS CORRESPONDENTE')` ou `re.compile(r'PEDIDOS DE TESTE(.*?)PROCESSOS CORRESPONDENTE', re.S | re.I)`).*

---

Não precisa de regex. Como as strings delimitadoras são fixas, uma combinação de `find` com [*slice*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211) já é o suficiente:

```py
def extrair_trecho(texto, trecho_inicial, trecho_final):
    pos_inicio = texto.find(trecho_inicial)
    if pos_inicio == -1: # se não encontrou o trecho inicial, retorna string vazia
        return ''
    # verifica se existe o trecho final, mas só procura depois da posição do trecho inicial
    pos_inicio += len(trecho_inicial)
    pos_fim = texto.find(trecho_final, pos_inicio)
    if pos_fim == -1: # se não encontrou o trecho final, retorna string vazia
        return ''
    # retorna o pedaço da string entre os trechos inicial e final
    return texto[pos_inicio:pos_fim]

texto = """Prezados,O faturamento desse mes foi de: R$ 15.000 Qualquer duvida que tiverem, podem me falar. Texto 1But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?Texto2At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.1914 translation by H. RackhamOn the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of the moment, so blinded by desire, that they cannot foresee the pain and trouble that are bound to ensue; and equal blame belongs to those who fail in their duty through weakness of will, which is the same as saying through shrinking from toil and pain. These cases are perfectly simple and easy to distinguish. In a free hour, when our power of choice is untrammelled and when nothing prevents our being able to do what we like best, every pleasure is to be welcomed and every pain avoided. But in certain circumstances and owing to the claims of duty or the obligations of business it will frequently occur that pleasures have to be repudiated and annoyances accepted. The wise man therefore always holds in these matters to this principle of selection: he rejects pleasures to secure other greater pleasures, or else he endures pains to avoid worse pains. Pedidos At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat. Reembolso But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?Onde posso arranjar algum?Existem muitas variações das passagens do Lorem Ipsum disponíveis, mas a maior parte sofreu alterações de alguma forma, pela injecção de humor, ou de palavras aleatórias que nem sequer parecem suficientemente credíveis. Se vai usar uma passagem do Lorem Ipsum, deve ter a certeza que não contém nada de embaraçoso escondido no meio do texto. Todos os geradores de Lorem Ipsum na Internet acabam por repetir porções de texto pré-definido, como necessário, fazendo com que este seja o primeiro verdadeiro gerador na Internet. Usa um dicionário de 200 palavras em Latim, combinado com uma dúzia de modelos de frases, para gerar Lorem Ipsum que pareçam razoáveis. Desta forma, o Lorem Ipsum gerado é sempre livre de repetição, ou de injecção humorística, etc.Porque é que o usamos?É um facto estabelecido de que um leitor é distraído pelo conteúdo legível de uma página quando analisa a sua mancha gráfica. Logo, o uso de Lorem Ipsum leva a uma distribuição mais ou menos normal de letras, ao contrário do uso de "Conteúdo aqui, conteúdo aqui", tornando-o texto legível. Muitas ferramentas de publicação electrónica e editores de páginas web usam actualmente o Lorem Ipsum como o modelo de texto usado por omissão, e uma pesquisa por "lorem ipsum" irá encontrar muitos websites ainda na sua infância. Várias versões têm evoluído ao longo dos anos, por vezes por acidente, por vezes propositadamente (como no caso do humor)."""

print(extrair_trecho(texto, 'Pedidos', 'Reembolso'))
```

Ou seja, primeiro eu procuro por "Pedidos". Se não encontrar, já retorna uma string vazia (mas você poderia mudar a função para lançar uma exceção, por exemplo). Se encontrar, eu procuro pelo trecho final, mas partindo da posição em que o trecho inicial foi encontrado.

No final, uso o *slice* para extrair somente o trecho da string que interessa (ou seja, entre as posições encontradas anteriormente).

Pode parecer que ficou pior porque "com regex é só uma linha", mas na verdade isso é mais rápido que a regex, [veja](https://ideone.com/Dg4G1s). Claro que para poucas strings a diferença será imperceptível, mas ainda sim veja que regex foi cerca de 12 vezes mais lenta (se tiver que processar muitos textos, *pode* começar a fazer diferença).

Vale notar que isso já resolve o problema das quebras de linha que você citou na sua resposta (com regex, precisaria ser algo como `re.search(r'Pedidos(.*?)Reembolso', texto, re.S).group(1)` - a *flag* `re.S` faz com que o ponto considere quebras de linha).

---

## Uma ou todas as ocorrências?

No código da pergunta você usou `findall` e em seguida percorreu os resultados com um loop. Isso quer dizer que pode ter mais de uma ocorrência?

Se for assim, `search` (que foi usado na [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/568233/112052)) não adianta. Neste caso, poderiar usar `findall` mesmo:

```py
import re
r = re.compile(r'Pedidos(.*?)Reembolso', re.S)
result = r.findall(texto)
```

A regex tem parênteses, o que forma um [grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). E quando há grupos na regex, `findall` retorna somente os grupos (assim não precisa mais usar `group`, como foi feito com `search`). E também mudei para [compilar a regex antes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/486258/112052), o que segundo a documentação deixa um pouco mais rápido (como veremos mais abaixo).

Se for para não usar regex, basta adaptar a função acima para continuar procurando as próximas ocorrências enquanto existirem:

```py
def extrair_trechos(texto, trecho_inicial, trecho_final):
    pos = 0
    while True:
        pos_inicio = texto.find(trecho_inicial, pos)
        if pos_inicio == -1: # se não encontrou o trecho inicial, encerra
            return
        # verifica se existe o trecho final, mas só procura depois da posição do trecho inicial
        pos_inicio += len(trecho_inicial)
        pos_fim = texto.find(trecho_final, pos_inicio)
        if pos_fim == -1: # se não encontrou o trecho final, encerra
            return
        pos = pos_fim + len(trecho_final)
        # retorna o próximo pedaço da string entre os trechos inicial e final
        yield texto[pos_inicio:pos_fim]

for trecho in extrair_trechos(texto, 'Pedidos', 'Reembolso'):
    print(trecho)
```

Ou seja, ele vai procurando pelo próximo trecho, até que não haja mais nenhum. Outra vantagem desta forma é que o uso do `yield` faz com que a função seja um *generator*, ou seja, ele processa um trecho e em seguida o descarta (isso economiza memória, caso você não precise manter todos os trechos em uma lista, por exemplo). Mas caso precise de uma lista contendo todos os trechos, bastaria fazer:

```py
# cria lista contendo todos os trechos
trechos = list(extrair_trechos(texto, 'Pedidos', 'Reembolso'))
```

No caso de `findall`, ele já retorna uma lista contendo os trechos. Mas se quisesse processar um a um e depois descartar, bastaria trocar por `finditer`:

```py
r = re.compile(r'Pedidos(.*?)Reembolso', re.S)
# finditer processa um trecho de cada vez, e depois descarta
for m in r.finditer(texto):
    trecho = m.group(1)
    # faz algo com o trecho
```

---

### Case insensitive

Por fim, se quer que as buscas sejam *case insensitive* (não diferenciam maiúsculas de minúsculas), basta adaptar a função acima para converter os trechos para um *case* em comum, antes de começar as buscas. No caso, usei `casefold`, que a [própria documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold) recomenda para buscas *case insensitive* (e vale ler também [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/544727/112052) para mais detalhes):

```py
def extrair_trechos(texto_original, trecho_inicial, trecho_final):
    texto = texto_original.casefold()
    trecho_inicial = trecho_inicial.casefold()
    trecho_final = trecho_final.casefold()
    pos = 0
    while True:
        pos_inicio = texto.find(trecho_inicial, pos)
        if pos_inicio == -1: # se não encontrou o trecho inicial, encerra
            return
        # verifica se existe o trecho final, mas só procura depois da posição do trecho inicial
        pos_inicio += len(trecho_inicial)
        pos_fim = texto.find(trecho_final, pos_inicio)
        if pos_fim == -1: # se não encontrou o trecho final, encerra
            return
        pos = pos_fim + len(trecho_final)
        # retorna o próximo pedaço da string entre os trechos inicial e final
        yield texto_original[pos_inicio:pos_fim]
```

Ou, com regex, basta usar a *flag* `re.I`, que habilita a busca *case insensitive*:

```py
r = re.compile(r'Pedidos(.*?)Reembolso', re.S | re.I)
result = r.findall(texto)
```

Neste caso, a diferença de desempenho entre as soluções diminui por causa do uso de `casefold`, [veja](https://ideone.com/HRL0OP) (mas ainda sim, a regex continua sendo mais lenta). Mas novamente, avalie se isso faz diferença para o seu caso.

Comment: que aula, excelente e muito obrigado pela ajuda vou testar mais aqui o que sugeriu obrigado, isso funcionou no primeiro teste sem problemas.

Answer (score -2):

Olá pessoal consegui pegar o texto que precisava com o seguinte codigo

```py
s = """Prezados,O faturamento desse mes foi de: R$ 15.000 Qualquer duvida que tiverem, podem me falar. Texto 1But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?Texto2At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.1914 translation by H. RackhamOn the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of the moment, so blinded by desire, that they cannot foresee the pain and trouble that are bound to ensue; and equal blame belongs to those who fail in their duty through weakness of will, which is the same as saying through shrinking from toil and pain. These cases are perfectly simple and easy to distinguish. In a free hour, when our power of choice is untrammelled and when nothing prevents our being able to do what we like best, every pleasure is to be welcomed and every pain avoided. But in certain circumstances and owing to the claims of duty or the obligations of business it will frequently occur that pleasures have to be repudiated and annoyances accepted. The wise man therefore always holds in these matters to this principle of selection: he rejects pleasures to secure other greater pleasures, or else he endures pains to avoid worse pains. Pedidos At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat. Reembolso But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?Onde posso arranjar algum?Existem muitas variações das passagens do Lorem Ipsum disponíveis, mas a maior parte sofreu alterações de alguma forma, pela injecção de humor, ou de palavras aleatórias que nem sequer parecem suficientemente credíveis. Se vai usar uma passagem do Lorem Ipsum, deve ter a certeza que não contém nada de embaraçoso escondido no meio do texto. Todos os geradores de Lorem Ipsum na Internet acabam por repetir porções de texto pré-definido, como necessário, fazendo com que este seja o primeiro verdadeiro gerador na Internet. Usa um dicionário de 200 palavras em Latim, combinado com uma dúzia de modelos de frases, para gerar Lorem Ipsum que pareçam razoáveis. Desta forma, o Lorem Ipsum gerado é sempre livre de repetição, ou de injecção humorística, etc.Porque é que o usamos?É um facto estabelecido de que um leitor é distraído pelo conteúdo legível de uma página quando analisa a sua mancha gráfica. Logo, o uso de Lorem Ipsum leva a uma distribuição mais ou menos normal de letras, ao contrário do uso de "Conteúdo aqui, conteúdo aqui", tornando-o texto legível. Muitas ferramentas de publicação electrónica e editores de páginas web usam actualmente o Lorem Ipsum como o modelo de texto usado por omissão, e uma pesquisa por "lorem ipsum" irá encontrar muitos websites ainda na sua infância. Várias versões têm evoluído ao longo dos anos, por vezes por acidente, por vezes propositadamente (como no caso do humor)."""

result = re.search(r'Pedidos(.*?)Reembolso',texto).group(1)

print(result)
```

Neste exemplo estou buscando dentro do texto somente o que estiver entre o texto pedido e reembolso, isso funcionou para min agora estou implementando para ele ler em um arquivo e fazer este processo, se alguém tiver um código melhor será bem vindo, uma observação importante isso só funciona se você remover as quebras de linha e tabs, já tenho este código pronto para fazer isso com o arquivo que vou ler.