# Como ler arquivo texto linha a linha

Tags: python, python-3.x, arquivo

Tenho um arquivo de texto com 3 linhas:

```
3.1415926535
8979323846
2643383279
```

E este código:

```
with open('txt_files\pidigits.txt') as arquivo_lido2:        
    String_com_dados_do_arquivo2 = arquivo_lido2.read()       
                                                            
for line in String_com_dados_do_arquivo2:
    print(line)
```

Ele deveria exibir as 3 linhas do arquivo, mas está exibindo o primeiro caractere de toda a cadeia no seguinte formato:

```
3
.
1
4
1
.....
```

Onde está o erro?

Comment: olá ja fez debug pra entender o que acontece no código?

Comment: Não agradeça, não cumprimente e não escreva novato no título da pergunta. Pelo menos faça o [tour] antes de usar o site. Nós somos um site de perguntas e respostas sobre linguagens de programação, não somos depurador ou adivinhe online. Veja [ask], [Como debugar programas pequenos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7785/137387), [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/101), [FAQ](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/699/137387) e [help]

Comment: Grato pela dica Augusto Vasques. Acho que estou na comunidade errada. vou para uma onde possa ser compreendido como novato neste ambiente. Assim que me tornar um pouco melhor, retornarei a esta comunidade para AJUDAR a outros como eu.

Comment: Na verdade o que o @AugustoVasques quis dizer é que não precisa colocar "sou novato" nem nada disso. Novatos são bem vindos e não tem problema nenhum (todos nós já fomos um dia). Só que não precisa colocar isso nas perguntas, pois a ideia do site é ter apenas as informações relevantes relacionadas diretamente à programação e ao problema técnico em si. O mesmo vale para cumprimentos e saudações: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/846/112052

Answer (score 1):

Segundo a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects), ao chamar `read()` sem parâmetros, ele lê **todo o conteúdo do arquivo** e retorna uma única string com este conteúdo (ou seja, você carregou o arquivo todo para a memória, o que não chega a ser um problema para arquivos pequenos).

E quando você faz um `for` em uma string, você está na verdade percorrendo os **caracteres** dela (e não as linhas). Por isso que o seu código imprime um caractere por vez.

Se quer percorrer as linhas do arquivo, faça o `for` no próprio arquivo:

```py
with open('arquivo.txt') as arquivo:
    for line in arquivo:
        print(line, end='')
```

Detalhe que a variável `line` também contém as quebras de linha, por isso adicionei o `end=''` para que o `print` não adicione mais uma quebra de linha depois de imprimir a linha.

---

Claro que também daria para usar `arquivo.readlines()`, que retorna uma lista contendo todas as linhas, mas tem um porém: `readlines` carrega todo o conteúdo do arquivo para a memória, enquanto que o `for` no arquivo processa uma linha de cada vez, e depois as descarta.

Então se vai somente processar linha a linha, mas não precisa ter todas as linhas em memória, o `for` como indicado acima já é suficiente.

---

<sup>Por fim, só para ser mais preciso, na verdade um `for` em uma string percorre os Unicode *code points* da mesma, que não é exatamente o mesmo que percorrer os caracteres (leia [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/394834/112052) para entender melhor).</sup>